# Передача лямбды в функцию по ссылке

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void qwer(const std::function<void()> &a)
{
        a();
}

int main()
{
        int x{0};

        auto f{
        [x]()mutable
        {
                std::cout << ++x << std::endl;
        }
        };

        qwer(f);
        qwer(f);
        qwer(f);

        return 0;
}
```

Выводит:

```
1
1
1
```

Есть 2 вопроса:

1. Почему компилятор не выдает ошибку? Ведь функция `qwer` ждет, что ей передадут функцию, а мы ей передаем лямбду, которая, на сколько я знаю, не является функцией.
2. Почему ,при передачи `f` в функцию `qwer` каждый раз создается копия `f`? Ведь при определении функции `qwer` при помощи `&` мы явно указали, что хотим использовать не копию объекта, а сам объект

Comment: У вас на каждый вызов `qwer` вызывается конструктор чтобы переобразовать лямбду в `std::function`. Лямбда при этом копируется. Вот вы и имеете три копии лямбды и у каждой своя копия `x`.

Comment: Разные типы, поэтому всегда будет конструировать `std::function`. Передавай через *perfect forwarding*, проверяй тип через концепт или метафункцию `enable_if` (для `C++17` и ниже).

Comment: `std::function` - может содержать в себе лямбды, функции (указатели), функторы (функциональные объекты) и объекты созданные, например, через `std::bind`. Вот здесь в самом начале всё написано https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. std::function умеет работать с лямбдами. [пруф](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

> Class template std::function is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper. Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any CopyConstructible Callable target -- functions, **lambda expressions**, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and pointers to data members.

2. Если я правильно понимаю, там создается копия, потому что тип у f другой. Но достаточно сделать явный тип

   ```
   std::function<void()> f{
    [x]()mutable
    {
            std::cout << ++x << std::endl;
    }
    };
   ```

и все работает как нужно.

Comment: Получается если я определил лямбду через `auto`, то нет никакой разницы между  `void qwer(std::function<void()> a)` и  `void qwer(const std::function<void()> &a)` ? Ведь и так и так будут созданы копии и вывод на экран будет `1 1 1`.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, что происходит, то тип лямбды и std::function не совпадают, но есть преобразование, которое может сделать из первого второе. И это преобразование - копирование.

Answer (score 1):

Объясню немного 2 вопрос.

Когда вы передаёте в функцию `qwer` лямбду, то т.к. она принимает аргумент типа `function`, то создается временный объект на который и ведет ссылка.

Вы можете удостоверится в этом добавив такую строчку в функцию `qwer`:

```
std::cout << &a << std::endl; //Вывести адрес
```

Сама лямбда у вас захватывает `x` по значению, по этому в каждом временном объекте своя копия `x`, нужно чтобы лямбда захватывала его по ссылке `&x`.

Поподробней и более умным языком написано [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-160).

То есть в вашем случае ссылка `function<void()>&` ведет на временный объект из-за различий в типах. А сама лямбда захватывает `x` по значению, а не по ссылке, по этому каждый временный объект работает с копией `x`.

Немного кода:

```
auto f{
    [&x]()mutable
    {
        std::cout << ++x << std::endl;
    }
};
```